# Nill value when passing data beetween related entities in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, optional-parameters

I'm trying for some days now (without success) saving on Core Data some properties of an entity ("Alumno") just after saving on its "children" viewController ("Especialidad") its related value.

Mine is a music teaching app, just as a contacts one. I pass the selected "Especialidad" (the played instrument in this case), after saving it to Core Data, for the correspondent "segue" to be performed, from its table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    especialidadSeleccionada = especialidades[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "GuardarEspecialidad", sender: self)
    }
```

to its related "parent", the complete pupil's data, containing this "Especialidad", among others properties.

Next, I try to save every pupil's data on Core Data:

```
if nombreField.text != "" && especialidadField.text != "" {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!
    AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext            
    let nuevoAlumno = Alumno(context: context)
    nuevoAlumno.nombre = nombreField.text!
            
    print("Data before: \(especialidadSeleccionada)")
    nuevoAlumno.especialidadRelacionada?.nombre =    especialidadSeleccionada?.nombre
    print("Data after: \(nuevoAlumno.especialidadRelacionada?.nombre)")
            
    //... and so on with the rest of properties
    
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
```

But it saves every property EXCEPT "nuevoAlumno.especialidadRelacionada?.nombre", marked as nill. As you can see, for debugging purposes, I print its value BEFORE the equality, obtaining a non-optional value, and AFTER it, getting... an optional value!!

I'm almost sure that it has to be something about their relationship. I've double-checked that "Especialidades" exact data is correct, but I really can't find the way to save "especialidad.nombre" in this "Alumno" entity...

An idea: maybe using "didSet" for that property of "Alumnos" could help? I've tried, but don't know how.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have reached to a solution. I was just using an incorrect property syntax:

```
nuevoAlumno.especialidadRelacionada = especialidadSeleccionada
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `nuevoAlumno.especialidadRelacionada` might be `nil`. Note that you're printing two different things in your before/after. I'd say set a breakpoint on this line:

```
nuevoAlumno.especialidadRelacionada?.nombre = especialidadSeleccionada?.nombre
```

and inspect all the values there.